# Consuming messages in parallel from ActiveMQ

Tags: java, concurrency, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

Whenever I am posting a message to the queue the first time the message gets picked up without any issue, but when I drop the second file the message is in the "pending" state the thread sleeping time (2 minutes). To test the Concurrency working in ActiveMQ I have added the bean called `ThreadService`.

I have the code like below in the JMSConfig.java

```java
@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setBrokerURL("tcp://localhost:61616");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("admin");
    connectionFactory.setUserName("admin");
    connectionFactory.setTrustedPackages(Arrays.asList("com.jms.domain", "java.util"));
    connectionFactory.setMaxThreadPoolSize(1);
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "stop", initMethod = "start")
@Primary
public PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory();
    pooledConnectionFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections("8");
    pooledConnectionFactory.setMaximumActiveSessionPerConnection("10");
    return pooledConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> queueListenerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setConcurrency("1-5");
    return factory;
}
```

> CamelRouter.java

```
from("file://E:/Camel")
    .bean(ThreadService)        
    .to("activemq:MessageQueue");
```

> ThreadService.java

```java
public void ThreadService throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(120000);
}
```

How can I achieve concurrency in ActiveMQ which dequeues message in pending state in parallel?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am confused because your question subject is about consuming and your route is producing to ActiveMQ

### Parallel consumers

If you want to **consume in parallel** from a JMS queue, you normally configure multiple consumers.

If you want to do this **for an individual consumer**, you can append it to the endpoint URI

```
from("activemq:queue:myQueue?concurrentConsumers=5"
```

if you want to apply this **as default for every consumer**, you can configure it in your bean setup

```
@Bean
public JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration() {
    JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration();
    jmsConfiguration.setConnectionFactory(pooledConnectionFactory());
    jmsConfiguration.setConcurrentConsumers(5);
    return jmsConfiguration;
}

@Bean(name = "activemq")
public ActiveMQComponent activeMq() {
    ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
    activeMQComponent.setConfiguration(jmsConfiguration()); 
    return activeMQComponent;
}
```

### Parallel producers

Well, your JMS producing route has a **file consumer that is per definition single threaded** to avoid processing the same file with multiple consumers.

However, you can **turn your route multithreaded** after file consumption with the [Threads DSL of Camel](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/async.html)

```
from("file://E:/Camel")
    .threads(5) // continue asynchronous from here with 5 threads
    .bean(ThreadService)        
    .to("activemq:MessageQueue");
```

Like this your "long running task" in `ThreadService` should no more block other files because the **route continues asynchronous with 5 threads** from the `threads` statement. The file consumer stays single threaded.

But be aware! **The `threads` statement breaks the current transaction**. The file consumer hands the message over to a new thread. If an error occurs later, the file consumer does not see it.

Comment: As i have mentioned above the code for camel is am picking up the file from my local folder path and to just check concurrency am doing a Thread.sleep() for 2 minutes and the MessageQueue waits for 2 minutes to move from Pending Messages to Dequeued... Can you suggest something for this scenario as ActiveMQ is the consumer here...

Comment: You mean you want to produce in parallel to ActiveMQ? ActiveMQ is the broker. Have you got a consumer somewhere else?

Comment: Spring JMS listener is the consumer here. camel is the posting the file that it pickedup using file component, Active MQ is the message store. if i drop two big files i want to consume and process them in parallel. Any way to achieve this ?

Comment: I have extended my answer since I think I understand you question better now

Comment: Thanks burki but the real problem for me is not residing in the camel layer itself when i drop 2 files the first file gets consumed as soon as it receives the file but the second file takes 2 minutes to receive as i have the Thread.sleep() for 2 minutes. hence i am not sure how to make the above work in parallel instead of not waiting for the message to process which is currently in sequential manner. Added a image to show what am seeing during the wait time.

Comment: Yeah, because your whole route is running in the same thread, the first file is consumed, then the message sleeps for 2 minutes, then it is produced to ActiveMQ and then finally the second file is consumed. With the `threads` added, the file consumer should hand over the message to another thread and instantly consume the second file.

Comment: Thanks burki for the information related to Thread DSL in camel which was a new learning for me in camel. The problem i see is in the listener and the spring listener is not working concurrently and if you see the edited screenshot it reaches till activemq and the message enqueued gets incremented but it is in Pending state rather than getting dequeued. Even without camel layer the behaviour is same with listener processing files only sequentially